# Sending http response after hijacking connection

Tags: http, go, websocket

What I try to achieve:
I want to recieve Http request from client then hijack the connection to monitor it on server side (Checking health of connection). Also I want to send Http response on that hijacked connection. In that order: recieve Http request, get request body, hijack connection, return response to client, monitor connection health on server side.

What I've already achieved:
Here is the code of http request handler:

```
func (c *HandlerCtx) HijackHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    // Fetching request body skipped

    // Hijacking the connection
    h, _ := w.(http.Hijacker)
    conn, br, err := h.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    responseBody := "Http response from hijacked connection"
    hr := http.Response{
        Status:           "200 OK",
        StatusCode:       200,
        Proto:            "HTTP/1.1",
        ProtoMajor:       1,
        ProtoMinor:       1,
        Header:           make(http.Header, 0),
        Body:             ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString(responseBody)),
        ContentLength:    int64(len(responseBody)),
        TransferEncoding: nil,
        Close:            false,
        Uncompressed:     false,
        Trailer:          nil,
        Request:          req,
        TLS:              nil,
    }

    // Writing response
    err = hr.Write(br)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Sending EOF to allow io.ReadAll(resp.Body) without blocking
    if  v, ok := conn.(interface{ CloseWrite() error }); ok {
        err = v.CloseWrite()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
    
    // Monitor connection health
}
```

This is the client code:

```
func main(){
    // Body skipped for testing purposes
    resp, err := http.Post("http://127.0.0.1:8085/hello", "application/json", nil)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

Now I recieve `unexpected EOF` from client after calling `err = v.CloseWrite()` but when I don't CloseWrite the client code stuck on `io.ReadAll(resp.Body)`

Is there any way to force client to read that http response? Please help me find solution.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Connection health monitoring is done by goroutine that tries to read data from connection and if there is an io.EOF error that means that client is disconnected. If it's about net/http server connection monitoring I tested that incoming connections are not closed even if the client app shutdown. Probably they are reused in some way and switching only from active to idle state(Done by: http/server ConnState)

Comment: @CeriseLimón I wanted to achieve it by upgrading to websocket to be able to monitor that connection from client to server, this connection need to be up for the whole lifetime of client application. I assume that this could be done by websockets but I could be wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you are duplicating builtin functionality. The net/http server cancels the [request context](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Context) when the client’s connection goes away.

Comment: Agreed but the client's connection goes away after getting a response that is why I wanted to use Hijack to keep that connection alive for whole app lifetime.